# How to add a new Sinatra endpoint to a dashing.io server?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dashing

Is there an easy way to add a new Sinatra endpoint to a [dashing.io](http://dashing.io/) server?

I'd like to incorporate a [Dropbox webhook](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/webhooks/docs) so that I can update a widget whenever a certain file changes in Dropbox. For that to work I have to add a new endpoint (e.g. https://www.example.com/dropbox-webhook) to the dashing.io server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to add endpoints here: [How to: Add authentication](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/How-to:-Add-authentication).